# Parsing morse code

Tags: algorithm, parsing, morse-code

I am trying to solve [this problem](http://uva.onlinejudge.org/index.php?option=onlinejudge&page=show_problem&problem=3554).
The goal is to determine the number of ways a morse string can be interpreted, given a dictionary of word.
What I did is that I first "translated" words from my dictionary into morse. Then, I used a naive algorithm, searching for all the ways it can be interpreted recursively.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <iterator>
using namespace std;

string morse_string;
int morse_string_size;
map<char, string> morse_table;
unsigned int sol;

void matches(int i, int factor, vector<string> &dictionary) {
    int suffix_length = morse_string_size-i;
    if (suffix_length <= 0) {
        sol += factor;
        return;
    }
    map<int, int> c;
    for (vector<string>::iterator it = dictionary.begin() ; it != dictionary.end() ; it++) {
        if (((*it).size() <= suffix_length) && (morse_string.substr(i, (*it).size()) == *it)) {
            if (c.find((*it).size()) == c.end())
                c[(*it).size()] = 0;
            else
                c[(*it).size()]++;
        }
    }

    for (map<int, int>::iterator it = c.begin() ; it != c.end() ; it++) {
        matches(i+it->first, factor*(it->second), dictionary);
    }
}

string encode_morse(string s) {
    string ret = "";
    for (unsigned int i = 0 ; i < s.length() ; ++i) {
        ret += morse_table[s[i]];
    }
    return ret;
}

int main() {
    morse_table['A'] = ".-"; morse_table['B'] = "-..."; morse_table['C'] = "-.-."; morse_table['D'] = "-.."; morse_table['E'] = "."; morse_table['F'] = "..-."; morse_table['G'] = "--."; morse_table['H'] = "...."; morse_table['I'] = ".."; morse_table['J'] = ".---"; morse_table['K'] = "-.-"; morse_table['L'] = ".-.."; morse_table['M'] = "--"; morse_table['N'] = "-."; morse_table['O'] = "---"; morse_table['P'] = ".--."; morse_table['Q'] = "--.-"; morse_table['R'] = ".-."; morse_table['S'] = "..."; morse_table['T'] = "-"; morse_table['U'] = "..-"; morse_table['V'] = "...-"; morse_table['W'] = ".--"; morse_table['X'] = "-..-"; morse_table['Y'] = "-.--"; morse_table['Z'] = "--..";
    int T, N;
    string tmp;
    vector<string> dictionary;
    cin >> T;

    while (T--) {
        morse_string = "";
        cin >> morse_string;
        morse_string_size = morse_string.size();
        cin >> N;
        for (int j = 0 ; j < N ; j++) {
            cin >> tmp;
            dictionary.push_back(encode_morse(tmp));
        }

        sol = 0;
        matches(0, 1, dictionary);
        cout << sol;

        if (T)
            cout << endl << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Now the thing is that I only have 3 seconds of execution time allowed, and my algorithm won't work under this limit of time.

Is this the good way to do this and if so, what am I missing ? Otherwise, can you give some hints about what is a good strategy ?

EDIT :
There can be at most 10 000 words in the dictionary and at most 1000 characters in the morse string.

Comment: And sorry I didn't say hi, editing doesn't work and I pressed enter too quickly :/

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic for StackOverflow because [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) is a better choice for reviewing/optimizing working code.

Comment: I'd personally say this was on topic here. Its not about the code, its about the algorithm behind the code and algorithms seem on topic to me. Just my thoughts.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark: The problem acknowledges this and I think the question is much better phrased as a "practical" problem with morse code than if it was using abritrary strings of ones and zeros with some arbitrary valid characters made up from those. In general though don't go criticizing how other people choose to spend their time.

Comment: Sounds like a dynamic programming problem.

Comment: An interesting problem. You could build a [trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) from the dictionary of phrases. Then it's a simple matter of reading each dot/dash and walking the trie. This would be very fast, providing that the dictionary isn't huge.

Comment: @JimMischel: I thought of that but the dictionary can contain up to 10 000 words (I edited my post to precise this).

Comment: 10,000 is a small number.

Answer (score 1):

A solution that combines dynamic programming with a [rolling hash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rolling_hash) should work for this problem.

Let's start with a simple dynamic programming solution. We allocate an vector which we will use to store known counts for prefixes of `morse_string`. We then iterate through `morse_string` and at each position we iterate through all words and we look back to see if they can fit into `morse_string`. If they can fit then we use the dynamic programming vector to determine how many ways we could have build the prefix of `morse_string` up to `i-dictionaryWord.size()`

```
vector<long>dp;
dp.push_back(1);
for (int i=0;i<morse_string.size();i++) {
   long count = 0;
   for (int j=1;j<dictionary.size();j++) {
       if (dictionary[j].size() > i) continue;
       if (dictionary[j] == morse_string.substring(i-dictionary[j].size(),i)) {
           count += dp[i-dictionary[j].size()];
       }
   }
   dp.push_back(count);
}
result = dp[morse_code.size()]
```

The problem with this solution is that it is too slow. Let's say that `N` is the length of `morse_string` and `M` is the size of the `dictionary` and `K` is the size of the largest word in the dictionary. It will do `O(N*M*K)` operations. If we assume `K=1000` this is about `10^10` operations which is too slow on most machines.

The `K` cost came from the line `dictionary[j] == morse_string.substring(i-dictionary[j].size(),i)`

If we could speed up this string matching to constant or log complexity we would be okay. This is where rolling hashing comes in. If you build a rolling hash array of `morse_string` then the idea is that you can compute the hash of any substring of `morse_string` in `O(1)`. So you could then do `hash(dictionary[j]) == hash(morse_string.substring(i-dictionary[j].size(),i))`

This is good but in the presence of imperfect hashing you could have multiple words from the dictionary with the same hash. That would mean that after getting a hash match you would still need to match the strings as well as the hashes. In programming contests, people often assume perfect hashing and skip the string matching. This is often a safe bet especially on a small dictionary. In case it doesn't produce a perfect hashing (which you can check in code) you can always adjust your hash function slightly and maybe the adjusted hash function will produce a perfect hashing.

Comment: Dynamic programming was indeed the right approach. However my solution doesn't use rolling hash ans passed the tests. I had never heard of rolling hash, so thank you for your suggestion, I learned something today!

Comment: @user3638414 You're welcome. I thought it would be too slow with just dynamic programming, but I guess I was wrong. Premature optimization :)